# How to Get value of a fields JSON with JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON format that I want get values fields using Java, but I can't resolve this problem, so it If someone can help me please

My JSON

```
    [
      {
       "logic":"and",
         "filters":
          [
           {
            "logic":"or",
             "filters":
              [
                 {
                  "field":"BatchPriority",
                  "operator":"eq",
                  "value":"1"
                 },
                 {
                  "field":"QPRPriority",
                  "operator":"eq",
                  "value":"2"
                 }
              ]
           }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

Here's how I consume it:

```
    JSONArray jsonFilters = (JSONArray) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonFormatted);
```

And I get my JSON, but how can I get now the value of the fields BatchPriority and QPRPriority?

> ```
> JSONArray jsonFilters = new JSONArray();
>       try {
>           jsonFilters = new JSONArray(jsonFormatted);
>       } catch (JSONException e1) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>           e1.printStackTrace();
>       }
>
>       JSONArray jsonFiltersNew = new JSONArray();
>       for (int i = 0; i < jsonFilters.length(); i++) 
>       {
>           JSONObject obj;
>
>           try {
>               jsonFiltersNew = new JSONArray(jsonFilters.getString(i));
>                   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
>               JSONArray array = jsonFilters.getJSONArray(i);
>                list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("filters"));
>           } catch (JSONException e) {
>               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           }
>           }
> ```

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation on `JSONObject` library?

Comment: Yes I tried it, since yesterday I can't resolve it :'(

Comment: Well then, post what you have tried.

Comment: BatchPriority and QPRPriority are the values of the field "field".